# POWERSHELL ODP.NET Tracing

Tags: oracle, powershell, trace, odp.net

Has anybody successfully implemented Oracle tracing with ODP.NET (Managed version) from within a Powershell script?  The ODP.NET calls  work in Powershell as expected, but it is not apparent that the config file is being read to set the tracing level and trace file destination, despite following the directions and placing app.config in the Powershell home directory.

app.config

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
   <version number="*">     
        <settings>
<!-- #OracleConfiguration.TraceFileLocation =".\traces";
#OracleConfiguration.TraceLevel = 7;    -->                   
             <setting name=”TraceLevel” value=”7" />
             <setting name=”TraceFileLocation” value=”.\traces\”/>
        </settings> 
    </version>
  </oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
</configuration>
```

This has always been squirrelly in Oracle anyway but seems to not work at all with Powershell...

Answer (score 0):

I ended up taking some c# sample code to get trace of the connection.

Does this work though
[How to add configuration options to ODP.Net Managed Driver in Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40974519/how-to-add-configuration-options-to-odp-net-managed-driver-in-powershell)